# How can I adjust the ViewHolder height in onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set the height of a ViewHolder in onBindViewHolder after changing its content but it only works at the beginning. When it gets recycled, the heights are wrong. I guess it keeps the height of the previous content. Why does it not adjust it again? What am I doing wrong?

My code (simplified):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);

        holder.mMyView.setText(holder.mItem.getValue());

        holder.mView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        );

        int layoutHeight = holder.mView.getMeasuredHeight();

        holder.mMyView.getLayoutParams().height = layoutHeight;


        //holder.mView.requestLayout();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final View mView;
        final TextView mMyView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mMyView= view.findViewById(R.id.myView);
        }
    }
```

Edit: My original code is a bit more complicated than this. I need to adjust the size of a view to match the size of another view. The code above is simplified to make it easier to read.

Edit 2: As requested, here is a simplified version of my XML to understand why I want to adjust the height. My goal is to adjust the ImageView height to match the height of the TextViews.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@imageView" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Edit 3: I just set the height to a fixed value now. Calculating the height had a big impact on the performance anyway. Ridiculous how difficult it is to make layouts responsive in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RecyclerView.LayoutManager has chooseSize() that might help you. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#chooseSize(int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: recyclerview.sethasfixed = false

Answer (score 0):

Simply set height of the TextView to `wrap_content` in its XML file. Then change the `onBindViewHolder` as following:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mMyView.setText(holder.mItem.getValue());
}
```

Height of the TextView will be change accordingly to its content.

Comment: My original code is a bit more complicated than this. I need to adjust the size of a view to match the size of another view. The code above is simplified to make it easier to read.

Comment: Could you please share XML file of the items.

Comment: Did you try to change imageView's height to `match_parent`?

Comment: Only worked with fixed parent height and I wanted to use wrap_content if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       //this is called when you scroll items
       //this will reset to origin xml default items
       //here heightChanged is the status , set true if changed
       if(heightChanged){
           //height according to logic 
        }else{
           //do nothing 
       }
    }
```

It seems like the height of items are different from each other, try adding status for height that has been changed (write logs to find out the height of each view you will get an idea how to solve this)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the height of Viewholder dynamically.just use,

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final View mView;
    final TextView mMyView;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mMyView= view.findViewById(R.id.myView);

        view.setMinimumHeight(600); // 600 you can type you height that you want...

    }
}
```